# Best sorting strategy using Mongoose and node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, query-performance

I've defined a mongoose document Note which contains 3 fields of type Date: created_on, updated_on and date. 
Only the latter is modified by the user while the rest are automatically set in backend.

```
var NoteSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: String, default: 'anonymous', trim: true },
  comments: { type: String, default: '', trim: true },
  date: {type: Date, default: function (){ return moment.utc() }, required: true},
  created_on: {type: Date, default: function (){ return moment.utc() } },
  updated_on: {type: Date, default: function (){ return moment.utc() } },  
  deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false }
});
```

This data is being consumed by a mobile app and it recovers the data.
The backend is returning the data using this sort option:

```
 options.sort = {
       date: -1,
       created_on: -1
 }
```

Currently there are very few documents because it's not on production but I'm wondering if this sorting strategy will fit  the requirement when the app were on production.
The only requirement is to show the user their latest notes but taking into account that he should be able to navigate all his notes (max. 6 months old).
This is similar to the way facebook app shows contents updates. the app loads the latest x documents and if the user wants to see older ones he must scroll and scroll...

I'm thinking about implementing a pagination system avoiding to use "skip" due to performance issues on large skips.
Maybe a good strategy would be to using .limit(MAX_DOCUMENTS), ordering by _id: -1 and the requesting the documents this way:

```
Note.find({_id: {$lt: older_id }}).sort({_id: -1}).limit(MAX_DOCUMENTS);
```

In this way the client (app) should perform the first query in a different way and next as the previous one.

For example:

1. First query: `Note.find().sort({_id: -1}).limit(10);`
2. Keep older `_id` (aka the 10th_id)
3. Next query:

   Note.find({_id: {$lt: id_previously_kept }}).sort({_id:
       -1}).limit(10);

Any suggestions about this?

Comment: You mean content lazyload... I have made an example web project in nodejs that brings cities(over 20000) 30 by 30 . When you scrollbar reachs bottom of the window, it fetch next 30 cities. You can have a look at here https://github.com/nodejstr/nodejs-lazyload

Comment: I am sure you have found a solution for this.  It would be a nice question to have in the forums if you could clean up the question to be a more straight forward question and provide your solution.